# Testing FFI Code (with "foreign import"s) with GHCi

Tags: haskell, ffi, ghci

Good (your local time of day), everyone.

I went through [Real World Haskell's chapter](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/interfacing-with-c-the-ffi.html) on the Foreign Function Interface,
and did some follow-up reading [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/FFI). I'm now experimenting with binding
to C functions, and I'd like some clarification on some things.

The following is fairly clear:

```
foreign import ccall unsafe "math.h sin" c_sin :: CDouble -> CDouble
```

I can load this and code that uses it in ghci, and everything is fine. It even
loads in the embedded ghci in emacs's Haskell mode. I find this great for testing.
`math` is a system library so this is straight-forward.

Now an example from Real World Haskell:

```
foreign import ccall unsafe "pcre.h pcre_compile" c_pcre_compile :: ...
```

I've left out the rest of the function signature on purpose. Now, I can't load this in
Haskell mode. All the examples I've seen say this must be done:

```
ghci -lpcre
```

Which I do, and get instant confirmation that things are loading properly:

```
GHCi, version 7.6.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Loading object (dynamic) /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/../../../../lib/libpcre.so ... done
final link ... done
```

I can then load my binding code and test away, but...

*_Question 1_* Can I load non-system libraries from within ghci, like pcre? This would
allow me to test within emacs.

Moving on.
Things get more complicated when I try to write bindings to my *own* C code.

```
foreign import ccall unsafe "myprint.h myprint" c_myprint :: CString -> IO ()
```

Admittedly a rather pointless function. It takes a ByteString from Haskell and
prints it with C. Here is a simple test file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
-- printTest.hs

import Foreign
import Foreign.C.Types
import Foreign.C.String

import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B

---

foreign import ccall unsafe "myprint.h myprint" c_myprint :: CString -> IO ()

---

main = B.useAsCString (B.pack "Tempura is great!") c_myprint
```

I have been able to compile this by doing:

```
ghc --make myprint.c printTest.hs
```

And get an executable, but I haven't been able to load it in ghci at all.
This severely lags the testing process.

*_Question 2_* What do I have to do to load Haskell code in ghci that binds to *my* C code?
None of the major sources of FFI information had anything to say about this.
No amount of fiddling with `ghci -L` could get it to work.

Please and thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Q2, you must compile myprint.c as a library if you want it to load in ghci. This is c compiler/ os dependent.

Comment: Along these lines (gcc -c -fPIC foo.c -o foo.o and then gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so.1 -o libfoo.so.1.0.1  foo.o) or something like that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ghci will load any library so long as it's valid for your architecture and can be located on some path.  On windows, pathnames with spaces used to cause problems, I don't know if they still do.

To load your own code in ghci, you need to first compile it, then tell ghci to load the output of that:

```
mybox$ gcc -c myprint.c
mybox$ ghci Myprint.hs myprint.o

*Main> main
Loading package array-0.4.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package deepseq-1.3.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package bytestring-0.10.0.2 ... linking ... done.
Tempura is great!
*Main>
```

You could also compile the C files into a library and load that into ghci, but for just one file using an object file is quite convenient.  If you want to create a library, a command like @Jonke suggested should work.  On my system (OSX),

```
mybox$ gcc -shared -fPIC myprint.c -o libmyprint.dylib
mybox$ ghci -L. -lmyprint Foo.hs
```

On my system it also works to just use the library filepath as an argument, but I don't know if that's portable.

Comment: `ghci myprint.o` This seems to be the simplest way. Thank you.

Comment: How could I proceed if myprint.o depends on a static C library contained in a relative directory(eg: lib/libx.a)

Comment: @ThiadodeArruda you'll need to add the necessary linker flags, as if you were compiling.  Something like `-Llib -lx -lmyprint` should work.  Linker flags can be sensitive to ordering though, so you may need to work a bit to find the correct ordering if you have a lot of libraries to link.