# Haskell FFI: stack run is ok, but GHCi does not link properly

Tags: haskell, ffi, haskell-stack, ghci

I am trying to learn how to structure a Haskell project/workflow that uses FFI.
I am using stack, but I find myself unable to use GHCi when it comes to the imported foreign functions.

Here is a simplified version of the problem. Let's say that I have the following two files in `$PROJECT_ROOT/cbits`:

**hello.h**

```c
#ifndef HELLO_H
#define HELLO_H

extern "C"
{
  int foo();
}

#endif /* HELLO_H */
```

**hello.cpp**

```
#include "hello.h"

#include <iostream>

int foo()
{
  std::cout << "extremely dangerous side effect" << std::endl;
  return 42;
}
```

My `Main.hs` file:

```hs
module Main where

import Foreign.C

foreign import ccall unsafe "foo" foo :: IO CInt

-- this does side effects and prints '42'
main = foo >>= print
```

The relevant (C++ specific) section of my `package.yaml` is:

```yaml
include-dirs:
  - cbits
cxx-sources:
  - cbits/*.cpp
cxx-options:
  - -std=c++17
extra-libraries:
  - stdc++
```

I am using the [souffle-haskell's `package.yaml`](https://github.com/luc-tielen/souffle-haskell/blob/master/package.yaml) as a reference.

Compiling and running with `stack run` is **ok** and I get the expected output:

```
extremely dangerous side effect
42
```

But, in the GHCi session (run with `stack ghci`), calling `main` gives:

```
ghc: ^^ Could not load 'foo', dependency unresolved. See top entry above.


GHC.ByteCode.Linker: can't find label
During interactive linking, GHCi couldn't find the following symbol:
  foo
This may be due to you not asking GHCi to load extra object files,
archives or DLLs needed by your current session.  Restart GHCi, specifying
the missing library using the -L/path/to/object/dir and -lmissinglibname
flags, or simply by naming the relevant files on the GHCi command line.
Alternatively, this link failure might indicate a bug in GHCi.
If you suspect the latter, please report this as a GHC bug:
  https://www.haskell.org/ghc/reportabug
```

The problem is **not** present if I compile `hello.cpp` beforehand:

```bash
g++ -c cbits/hello.cpp -o cbits/hello.o
```

And then run `stack ghci --ghci-options cbits/hello.o`, as suggested by the GHCi error message.

Question is: do I *really* need to maintain a separate `*.o` file specifically for GHCi? Searching online I have found discussions addressing only the GHCi part or the stack/cabal part, but not both. The only useful answer that I have found is [this one from 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15679196/20683133), which reaffirms the "solution" given by GHCi and does not mention stack or cabal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question is: do I *really* need to maintain a separate `*.o` file specifically for GHCi?

Answer is: no.
After several tries, the *only* thing that I had to change was the name of an option:

```
- cxx-sources:
+ c-sources:
```

This left the behaviour of `stack run` unchanged, and allowed GHCi to link properly to the compiled code.